# What is the expected value of this game for large N?

Tags: probability, asymptotics, expected-value

For a given even $N$, I have $N/2$ red cards and $N/2$ black cards. Each time I draw a black card I win a dollar, each time I draw a red card I lose a dollar.  I can stop at any time I like (and choose to do so in such a way that would maximize my expected winnings).

What is the expected value of the game for large $N$?

For a simple example, when $N=2$ - I would draw a card and if it's red, I would draw again (to get value of $0$), and if it's black I would stop, resulting in expected value of $0.5$.

To clarify, I know how to compute this numerically. I'm interested in the functional form for large $N$. For what it is worth, from simulations it appears to be ${\cal O}(\sqrt{N})$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92047/discussion-on-question-by-confucious-what-is-the-expected-value-of-this-game-for).

Comment: "from simulations it appears to be..." In these simulations you must be employing some sort of stopping criterion.  What criterion do you use to stop playing the game in these simulations?

Comment: (as mentioned in comments earlier) I just solve the recursion: $E(r, b) = max(r/(r+b) (E(r-1,b) - 1) + b/(r+b) (E(r, b-1) + 1), 0)$

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544045/optimal-stopping-in-red-vs-black-card-game-deck-of-52-cards)

Comment: If it helps anyone, the matrix $M$ with entries $M_{i,j} = E(i,j)$ is very nearly symmetric about the anti-diagonal.  [Here's the picture up to 5000x5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1UgK.png).  To put the pic in perspective, the maximum value is at the top right with 5000 black cards and no red cards.  Purple areas = expected value of 0.

Comment: "from simulations it appears" How large have you run these simulations?

Comment: @Scott up to N=200k

Comment: Don't know if this helps but this game is called the Larry Shepp urn game, by Larry Shepp of Rutgers.

Comment: From @I.J.Kennedy's clue, it looks like Shepp's paper discussing the matter can be found [here](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1262&context=statistics_papers).  A cursory examination suggests that Theorem 4.3 might answer your conjecture in the affirmative.

Comment: In this game we know that there are $\frac{N}2$ cards of each colour to begin with. In the Shepp urn game we don't know how many cards of each colour there are to begin with - each of the initial cards is independently chosen to be either red or black.

Comment: I had a very similar [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614468/an-extrasensory-perception-strategy) years ago.

Comment: Investigating yours, by induction we can easily prove that $E(r,b)=\tfrac{b(b+1-r)}{b+1}$ for each $0\le r\le 2$ and $b\ge 0$. Unfortunately, this simple pattern breaks for $r=3$. Namely, 
$E(3,b)=\left(0,0,\frac 1{5},\frac {17}{20},\frac{89}{70},\frac{967}{420},\dots\right).$

Comment: So I failed to found a constant $c$ such that $E(N,N)=c\sqrt{N}+o(\sqrt{N})$. But sometimes such a constant can be guessed as follows. :-) Calculate it suggested numerical value with sufficiently high precision. Say, ten digits after the dot. Then google this value, removing the last digit until you find a link to a possible candidate.

Comment: @AlexRavsky the constant is actually given in the paper referenced above right after equation 6.7, but honestly I don't understand the paper/proof, and would happily settle for an argument that just shows that it's ${\cal O}(\sqrt N)$ without computing the constant. Of course if someone can digest and summarize the derivation with the constant - that would be great too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Letting $E_N$ be the optimal expected value for even $N$, we can show that
$$
E_N\sim c\sqrt N
$$
for $N$ large, where $c\approx 0.369136$.

I will give a rough argument, which it should be possible to make rigorous by going through the details. Define a process $X^N_t$ for $0\le t\le 1$ as follows. Let $X^N_{k/N}$ be the number of black cards minus the number of red cards after $k$ have been selected. We interpolate in the range $[(k-1)/N,k/N)$ as constant. This is a random walk conditioned on $X_1=0$. Scaling, $N^{-1/2}X^N_t$ converges, in distribution, to a limit $X$ which is a standard Brownian bridge on the interval $[0,1]$ (i.e., a standard Brownian motion conditioned on $X_1=0$). So, commuting the limit with the supremum,
$$
N^{-1/2}E_N=\sup_\tau E[N^{-1/2}X^N_\tau]\to\sup_\tau E[X_\tau].
$$
The supremum is taken over stopping times $0\le\tau\le 1$.
So, $E_N\sim c\sqrt N$ where $c=\sup_\tau E[X_\tau]$ is the solution to the continuous-time version of the game described.

To solve for $c$, let $f(t,x)$ be the solution starting from $X=x$ at time $t$. That is,
$$
f(t,x)=\sup_{\tau\ge t} E[X_\tau\vert X_t=x].
$$
By considering $\tau=t$ and $\tau=1$, we see that $f(t,x)\ge\max(x,0)$. We need to compute $c=f(0,0)$. We can reduce the dimensionality of the problem: by a simple symmetry, for each fixed time $t$, the process $Y_s=(1-t)^{-1/2}X_{t+s(1-t)}$ is also a Brownian motion conditioned on $Y_1=0$. So,
$$
\begin{align}
f(t,x)&=\sup_{\tau} E[X_{t+\tau(1-t)}\vert X_t=x]\\
&=\sup_\tau(1-t)^{1/2} E[Y_\tau\vert Y_0=(1-t)^{-1/2}x]\\
&=(1-t)^{1/2}g((1-t)^{-1/2}x)
\end{align}
$$
where I am setting $g(x)=f(0,x)$. Next, the Brownian bridge satisfies the Stochastic differential equation
$$
dX_t = dW_t - (1-t)^{-1}X_tdt
$$
for standard Brownian motion $W$.
On the domain where $f(t,x) > x$ then $f(t,X_t)$ is locally a martingale, so it satisfies the Kolmogorov backward equation (PDE),
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f+\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f-(1-t)^{-1}x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f=0.
$$
Substituting in the expression for $f$ in terms of $g$ gives a linear ODE
$$
g^{\prime\prime}(y)-yg^{\prime}(y)-g(y)=0.
$$
This has the general solution
$$
g(y)=e^{y^2/2}(a+bN(y))
$$
for constants $a,b$, where $N(y)=(2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^ye^{-t^2/2}dt$ is the cumulative normal distribution function. As $g$ is increasing, it cannot blow up in the limit $y\to-\infty$, so we have $g(y)=be^{y^2/2}N(y)$ on the domain $g(y) > y$. Plugging in $y=0$ gives $c=g(0)=b/2$, so $g(y)=2ce^{y^2/2}N(y)$ over $g(y) > y$. As $g(y)$ cannot blow up faster than linearly in $y$, there must be a $y_0 > 0$ for which $2ce^{y_0^2/2}N(y_0)=y_0$, so that $g(y)=y$ for $y > y_0$. The optimal value of $c$ for which this holds is given by
$$
c=\sup_{y > 0}\frac{ye^{-y^2/2}}{2N(y)}.
$$
By differentiating, the function of $y$ on the right has a unique local maximum. I am not sure if there is an analytic solution, but I tried in wolfram alpha. Expressing in terms of the error function,
$$
c=\sup_{y > 0}\frac{ye^{-y^2/2}}{1+{\rm erf}(y/\sqrt2)}
$$
we get $c\approx0.369136$.

---

For comparison, I also computed the $\alpha$ in the [linked paper](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1262&context=statistics_papers) as $\alpha\approx0.839923675692373$, so $c=(1-\alpha^2)(\pi/2)^{1/2}\approx 0.369136$ and we are in agreement.

Comment: Agrees with numerical evaluation.

Comment: For the game value $E_N$ to asymptotically match the expected supremum of the underlying process, the optimal strategy must be able to achieve expected return within $o(\sqrt{N})$ of this supremum. Why is that the case?