# Optimal stopping in red vs black card game deck of 52 cards, quick way to reasonably estimate the answer

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, estimation, card-games

Here is a question asked on MSE a few years ago:
[Optimal stopping in red vs black card game deck of 52 cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544045/optimal-stopping-in-red-vs-black-card-game-deck-of-52-cards)

> Imagine you are playing a card game you start with a well shuffled deck of $52$ cards, containing $26$ red cards and $26$ black cards, stacked face down. You have a sequence of turns, $52$ possible turns in total, each turn you either pull the top card and turn it over, or you quit. If you pull a red card you win $1$, and if you pull a black card you lose $1$.  If you played all $52$ turns without stopping you are guaranteed to break even. What is the optimal stopping strategy?

---

There is an answer given there by quasi:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2544082/834963

Let $v(r,b)$ be the expected value of the game for the player, assuming optimal play, if the remaining deck has $r$ red cards and $b$ black cards.

Then $v(r,b)$ satisfies the recursion
$$
v(r,b) =
\begin{cases}
0&\;\text{if}\;r=0\\[4pt]
r&\;\text{if}\;b=0\;\text{and}\;r>0\\[4pt]
\max(0,f(r,b))&\;\text{if}\;r,b>0\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
where 
$$
f(r,b) = 
\left({\small{\frac{r}{r+b}}}\right)(1+v(r-1,b))
 +
\left({\small{\frac{b}{r+b}}}\right)(-1+v(r,b-1))
$$
The stopping rule is simple: Stop when $v(r,b)=0$.

To explain the recursion . . .

If $r,b>0$, and the player elects to play a card, then:

- The revealed card is red with probability ${\large{\frac{r}{r+b}}}$, and in that case, the player gets a score of $+1$, and the new value is $v(r-1,b)$.$\\[4pt]$

  The revealed card is black with probability ${\large{\frac{b}{r+b}}}$, and in that case, the player gets a score of $-1$, and the new value is $v(r,b-1)$.

Thus, if $r,b>0$, electing to play a card yields the value $f(r,b)$.

But the player always has the option to quit, hence, if $r,b>0$, we get $v(r,b) = \max(0,f(r,b))$.

Implementing the recursion in Maple, the value of the game is
$$v(26,26) = \frac{41984711742427}{15997372030584}\approx 2.624475549$$
and the optimal stopping strategy is as follows . . .

- If $24 \le b \le 26$, play while $r \ge b - 5$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $17 \le b \le 23$, play while $r \ge b - 4$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $11 \le b \le 16$, play while $r \ge b - 3$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $6 \le b \le 10$, play while $r \ge b - 2$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $3 \le b \le 5$, play while $r \ge b - 1$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $1 \le b \le 2$, play while $r \ge b$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $b = 0$, play while $r > 0$.

---

However, given that this question was asked as part of a job interview, I don't think it's very realistic to get $2.62$ in a short amount of time. I was wondering if there a quick way to:

1. Find the optimal stopping rule in terms of maximizing expected payoff.
2. Get an estimate close to the actual answer of around $2.62$ without laborious recursive calculation or writing a program.

Comment: Eyeballing it, it looks like you play while $r \ge b - \sqrt{b}$. Perhaps there's an easy heuristic to get there.

Comment: Not sure it's feasible to pull off in an interview, but you can approximate the expected value/optimal stopping rule by looking at the continuous version of the problem: the optimal stopping of a Brownian Bridge.

https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/AC73024AFDDD7FE2127B4123F3978FF9/S0021900200005295a.pdf/optimal-stopping-of-a-brownian-bridge.pdf

Comment: @JRichey That's a different problem where the payout is determined *only* by the last card after stopping. Here, there's a payout for *every* card drawn. You can certainly do better than breaking even - you can *never do worse* than breaking even (by simply drawing all cards), and it's possible to do better by simply stopping at a time when you have a positive value. The expected value must be positive, since it's possible to win money but impossible to lose money.

Comment: A simple heuristic that probably gives the right order of magnitude: the probability that a bridge reaches height $\sqrt{n}$ is constant order. So you can just pick a height on that order and stop when you hit it, with expected value constant root $n$. Finding the best constant might even be doable in the large $n$ limit using the distribution for the maximum of a Brownian bridge.

Comment: Technically they might just want to check how familiar the job candidate was with the standard literature like https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253218287_Optimal_Stopping_of_a_Brownian_Bridge Once you know that the standard Brownian bridge on $[0,1]$ has the optimal stopping value of about $0.37$, you can just scale it by $\sqrt{52}$ to get $2.66$, which is a bit optimistic due to the actual process being discrete, but only a little bit. The strategy expected was just the natural discretization of the continuous strategy, which was also, probably, assumed known to the candidate.

Answer (score 1):

### Look for the 'pivot points' and make continuous approximations

Here's *part of* an answer...

If we do some handwaving and approximations we can get something more compact without actually doing the computations.

First, simplifying the notation of $v$ and $f$, we can combine into $q$ notation: q depends on both state and action, and is the expected value of taking the proposed action in the state and then acting optimally thereafter.

Using [Bellman's optimal q equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation), writing $q(r, b)$ for the quality of the action $\operatorname{play}$ in state $(r, b)$ (the quality of the action $\operatorname{stop}$ is always $0$)

$$q(r, b) = \frac {r} {r+b}\left(1 + \max(0, q(r-1, b))\right) + \frac {b} {r+b}\left(-1 + \max(0, q(r, b-1))\right)$$

The point of the question is to determine when $q(r, b) > 0$ (i.e. we should take the $\operatorname{play}$ action) and also what is $q(26, 26)$. What follows makes some progress toward the former.

So the criterion is

$$q(r, b) > 0$$

#### First handwave: in the region of $0$, less $r$ is 'bad', less $b$ is 'good'

Those $\max$ expressions sure make this fiddly!

Let's look for 'pivot points' where $q \simeq 0$.

Assuming $q$ is roughly continuous, when we're near (in $(r, b)$-space) $q(r, b) = 0$ we should expect that reducing $r$ pushes us into negative territory. And we should assume that reducing $b$ pushes us into positive territory.

So 'near a pivot' we can say

$$\max(0, q(r-1, b)) = 0$$
$$\max(0, q(r, b-1)) = q(r, b-1)$$

and also

$$\frac {\partial q} {\partial r}(r, b) > 0$$
$$\frac {\partial q} {\partial b}(r, b) < 0$$

#### Second handwave: small changes in $r$, and $b$ have roughly linear effects

This is basically a Taylor assumption. I don't justify it here, but it seems intuitively sensible for the domain in question.

Now we can say things like, near a pivot where $q(r, b) = 0$

$$\max(0, q(r-1, b)) = \max\left(0, q(r, b) - \frac {\partial q} {\partial r}(r, b)\right) = 0$$
$$\max(0, q(r, b-1)) = \max\left(0, q(r, b) - \frac {\partial q} {\partial b}(r, b)\right) = -\frac {\partial q} {\partial b}(r, b)$$

#### Putting it together and 'solving'

Now we have, near a 'pivot point' where $q(r, b) \simeq 0$,

$$q(r, b) \simeq \frac r {r+b} + \frac b {r+b}\left(-1 - \frac {\partial q} {\partial b}(r, b)\right)$$

So we have a first order partial differential equation for $q$ in $b$

$$0 \simeq r + b \left(-1 - \frac {\partial q} {\partial b}\right)$$

Separating,

$$\frac {\partial q} {\partial b} = -1 + \frac r b$$

and solving

$$q = - b + r \ln b + c_r(r)$$

I'm not sure what handwaves are required, but intuitively we should be able to do some similar tricks to get

$$q = r + c_b(b)$$

and from there

$$q = r - b + r\ln b + c$$

which yields the criterion (for some $c$ to be determined, perhaps by inspecting small $r$, $b$ cases)

- Play while $r > \frac {b + c} {1 + \ln b}$

*Presumably* an appropriate $c$ is small, maybe zero, since for small $r$ and $b$, $r-b$ is a good criterion.

#### Finding $q(26, 26)$

The above solution should not be expected to extrapolate usefully 'away from pivots', since many of the assumptions require being in the region of a pivot. So we can't use this to answer the other part of the question.

Comment: One trouble with this fun theorising is that it doesn't seem to work very well! The factor $\frac 1 {1 + \ln b}$ discounts more rapidly than the brute force calculated optimal criterion (which appears closer to $1 - \sqrt(b)$)

Comment: Thanks Oly. How is one able to get something close to $2.62$ from what you wrote without laborious calculation?

Answer (score 1):

For large $r, b$ with $\frac rb$ close to $1$, we should expect the game to be approximately unchanged after replacing each $+1$ card with four cards $+\frac12, +\frac12, +\frac12, -\frac12$, and each $-1$ card with four cards $+\frac12, -\frac12, -\frac12, -\frac12$, since the replacements have the same sum and variance over a given fraction of the deck.  In other words, doubling $b - r$ while quadrupling $r + b$ should approximately double the game value.  So the optimal stopping criterion should have $b - r$ approximately proportional to $\sqrt{r + b}$.

Comment: Thanks Anders. How is one able to get something close to $2.62$ from what you wrote without laborious calculation or writing a program?