# Maximal expected payoof example with an Urn

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Consider an urn with $w$ red and $w$ black balls. We repeatedly draw balls out of said **urn without replacement**. (For clearity we stre that after $2w$ draws the urn is empty.) We get $ 1\$ $ for every red ball and we have to pay $ 1\$ $ for every black ball; if we draw all balls we get nothing. Compute the maximum expected payoff via backward recursion and compute it explicitly for $n = 100$.

I recognise that this exercise is intended to be solved with help of the following theorem:

> Consider a "game" (such as the one above) with $N$ draws and let $Z_n$ denote the amount of money the player recieves if he stops at time $n$. Then $U_0 := \max_T \mathbb{E}[Z_T]$, where $T$ runs over all stopping times $T \le N$, models the maximum expected payoff. More generally we model the information flow of the player by a finite filtration $\mathcal{F}$ and let$U_n := \max_{T_n} \mathbb{E}[Z_T \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$ for $0 \le n \le N$, where $T_n$ denotes the set of stopping times in $\{n, \ldots, N\}$.
> We can determine $(U_n)_n$ via backwards recursion $U_N = Z_N$ and $$U_{n-1} = \max(Z_{n-1}, \mathbb{E}[U_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}])$$ for $1 \le n \le N$.

I think we should model the urn draws by the RVs $(X_n)_{1 \le n \le N}$ that map into $\{\pm 1\}$, but I do not get how to choose the probability of the $(X_n)_n$; the assumption that we do not put back the balls makes this difficult for me. Furthermore, I guess we should set $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{\Omega,\emptyset \}$, $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ for $n \ge 1$ and $Z_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Could you please tell me how to choose the pmf of the $(X_n)_n$?

Comment: The hint, to use backwards induction, is a good one.  Consider states indexed by the number of red and black balls remaining.  Then, given the state, we can easily compute the value of stopping the game then, and by induction we can see the value of the option to draw again.

Comment: Note: this is a well known problem, though it is usually presented in terms of a deck of $2n$ cards (with $n$ red and $n$ black).  As such it is popularly known as the Red-Black Card problem.  See, for instance, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544045/optimal-stopping-in-red-vs-black-card-game-deck-of-52-cards)